# Looking for a Latex Template for an Entire Academic Journal not just Each Article

Tags: templates, journal-publishing

I would like to create an in-house journal similar to an academic journal with multiple submissions in latex. The front should have a list of articles and a comment from the editor. Each submission should have its own abstract and authors. What I need is a template that does this and is nice-looking. Anyone have any suggestions ?